# error: the < operator is undefined for the arguments type(s) Double[], double

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I know this is quite basic but I am having trouble understanding to use `<` when testing against objects in an array.

I want to test the `ruleGrades` which are stored in an 2D array against `minimum` (a `double`), and then multiply it with a `probability` (`double`).

```
ArrayList<Double[][]> ruleGrades  = new ArrayList<Double[][]>();
ArrayList<Double> min= new ArrayList<Double>();
double minimum;

System.out.println("Rule Grades: "+ruleGrades.toString());
        for(int a=0;a<ruleGrades.size();a++)
        {
            minimum=2.0;
            System.out.println("A: "+a);
            for(Double[] grades : ruleGrades.get(a))
            {
                if(grades<minimum) //error over here
                {
                    Double prob=rule.getRules().get(a).getProbability();
                    minimum=grades.doubleValue()*prob.doubleValue(); //error  
                }
            }
            min.add(minimum);
        }
        max=0.0; //finding largest
        for (int b = 0; b< min.size(); b++ )
        {
            if( min.get(b) > max)
            {
                max = min.get(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay I see that i dont need a multidimensional array, I can just use a Double[] to have 2 values in the first element. Here is my updated code:

```
ArrayList<Double[]> ruleGrades  = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
ArrayList<Double[]> min= new ArrayList<Double[]>();


System.out.println("Rule Grades: "+ruleGrades.toString());
        for(int a=0;a<ruleGrades.size();a++)
        {
            Double [] minimum={2.0,2.0};
            System.out.println("A: "+a);
            for(Double grades : ruleGrades.get(a))
            {
                if(grades<minimum[0])
                {
                    Double prob=rule.getRules().get(a).getProbability();
                    minimum[0]=grades.doubleValue()*prob.doubleValue();
                }
                if(grades<minimum[1])
                {
                    Double prob=rule.getRules().get(a).getProbability();
                    minimum[1]=grades.doubleValue()*prob.doubleValue();
                }
            }
            min.add(minimum);
        }
        Double [] max= {0.0,0.0}; //finding largest
        for (int b = 0; b< min.size(); b++ )
        {
            for(Double mins : min.get(b))
            {
                if( mins> max[0])
                {
                    max = min.get(b);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

So in my first IF statement I want to check if the first double is less than 2.0, then multiple it by the probability and then add it to the arraylist min.

But how would I do that for the second value in the same element. 
For example ruleGrades contains: [1.7,1.9],[1.2,1.3] ....
Then i take 1.7 multiply by prob (lets just say its 1) and add to the Double[] in the min arraylist, so min will look like this [1,7]. But then I wish to the same for 1.9 and put it in the same element as 1.7, so then the min array will look like [1.7,1.9].
Thats why i have added another IF statement , is this correct?

After all the grades have been multiplied by the prob and added to the min arraylist, i need to find the biggest one. So i made a Double max[] is that correct ?

Sorry about this, I am trying to read but I am really confused.
Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: When and how is an array smaller than a number? What do you hope to check with `grades<minimum`?

Comment: You do know that `ruleGrades` is a *3D* array, right?

Comment: Are you sure about what you trying to achieve? `grades<minimum` doesn't make any sense. What you want to compare?

Comment: so basically ruleGrades contains doubles, there are 2 grades for each element thats why i used a Double[][], so ruleGrades is populated with doubles before this. Now i want to compare the elements and make sure they are less than 2, and then go into the IF and multiple it by the probability. So for example if ruleGrades[0][0] = 1.7,1.9 then I want to multiple each of these double values with a rule probability and save that in another array which i call min

Comment: @ukbaz ‘*`ruleGrades` contains `double`s*’ No, it contains arrays of arrays of `double`s. ‘*there are 2 grades for each element thats why I used a `Double[][]`*’ That doesn't make any sense. Two `doubles` would fit in a `Double[]`. ‘*`ruleGrades[0][0] = 1.7,1.9`*’. That makes no sense either. `ruleGrades[0][0]` is a *single* value. I think you need to read up on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you have declared array in inner for loop and comparing the whole array to a single double value.

**`grades < minimum` is the problem**

```
for(Double[] grades : ruleGrades.get(a))
{
    if(grades is an array of Double < minimum is a double )  //error over here
     {
```